# Different Tomcat Instances on Windows

Tags: java, tomcat

I currently have Apache Tomcat 7 running on my Windows 7 Professional laptop working with Java 6 JDK etc and all works well with a project it is setup for.  But I now have another requirement to ALSO have a Tomcat 8 running with Java 8 JDK.  I have Windows environment variables set up as follows;

```
CATALINA_HOME C:\Apache\tomcat
CLASSPATH JAVA_HOME\lib
JAVA_HOME C:\Java\jdk6_30U
JRE_HOME  C:\Java\jre6_30U
```

I have downloaded Java 8 and installed the JDK and JRE fine in C:\Java\Java8 and left the Java environment variables alone.  At the command prompt it says the Java version is 1.8.0.7 but the project running Java 6 still works fine.  I have now extracted Tomcat 8 into C:\Apache\tomcat8 and I know I can't have conflicting port numbers but how do I set up Tomcat 8 to use java 8 JDK and NOT conflict with the CATALINA_HOME environment variable?

I have googled this but there are conflicting feedback with some saying set up a setenv.bat file and some saying amend the catalina.bat file or even the startup.bat file.  How do I set the environment variables to use the appropriate ones with the different Tomcat instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new file `startup-with-java8.bat` in Tomcat's bin folder:

```
@echo off
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Apache\tomcat8
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\Java8
set JRE_HOME=C:\Java\Java8
call %~dp0\startup.bat %*
```

And use new script to start Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for response.  Sorry for delay in feedback but it was the weekend here.  I tried your suggestion above but unfortunately it simply flashes up a blank DOS screen and that is all

Comment: Do you have any log on command line? Something like this: `Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30"`

Comment: No, the command prompt (dos) window which appears is blank and only appears for a split second.  Also the logs folder for Tomcat8 is still empty

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have it working.  Instead of just double clicking on the new start file I opened a command prompt, navigated to the bin directory and entered startup_with_java8.bat and this told me the JRE_HOME environment variable was not defined correctly.  So changed it from C:\Java\Java8 to the correct path of C:\Java\Java8\jre1_8_0_71U and similarly the JAVA_HOME from C:\Java\Java8 to C:\Java\Java8\jdk1_8_0_71U and it all appears to work.